# How to use css_parser to get this property?

Tags: python, css, parsing

I want to print the "woff" url for each "font-family", but `css_parser.CSSParser().style.property.value` is an atomic string that cannot be divided.

How to write the code ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import css_parser

CSSstr='''
@font-face {
    font-family: "Arial";
    src: url("https://www.com/test1.eot");
    src: url("https://www.com/test1.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://www.com/test1.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://www.com/test1.woff") format("woff"), url("https://www.com/test1.svg") format("svg");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Arial Italic";
    src: url("www.com/test2.eot");
    src: url("www.com/test2.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("www.com/test2.woff2") format("woff2"), url("www.com/test2.woff") format("woff"), url("www.com/test2.svg") format("svg");
}
'''

parser = css_parser.CSSParser()
sheet = parser.parseString(CSSstr)

for rule in sheet:
    if rule.type == 5:
        # find property
        for property in rule.style:
            if property.name == 'font-family':
                print(property.value)
            if property.name == 'src':
                print(property.value)
```

I want a output like:

```
Arial
https://www.com/test1.woff
Arial Italic
https://www.com/test2.woff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, it is just an atomic string.

**Workaround**: use regular expression to capture your data.

```
import re

...

for rule in sheet:
    if rule.type == 5:
        # find property
        for property in rule.style:
            if property.name == 'font-family':
                print(property.value)
            if property.name == 'src':
                match = re.search(r'.*url\((.*woff)\)\.*', property.value)
                print(match.group(1))
```

Expression explanation:

- `.*url\(` some string started by any chars and then  `url(`.
- `(.*woff)` the data to be captured. Any text finished by `woff`.
- `\)\.*` finishing by `)` and then any text.

I hope this will be a solution for you.